# Overriding events of a base event to an application and sequence of flow c#

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, events, coding-style

What is the best way or best practice to propagate events from a base class (and handle them at the base as well) to the inherited or implementing application - because I want all the code to execute from the base to the MyClientListener to the Winform ?

I have a [WCF DuplexClient] class which other [WCF ClientListener] classes will derive from. I want to make it reusable for all of my services. I have an event InnerChannel_Faulted - in this base class I have an initializer in the base class which subscribes to events and the base class will generally handle these as far as the WCF side of things goes. I want to also be able to have my specific ClientListener implementation to be able to provide additional functionality - behavior to those events - mostly for the Winforms Application.

Is my thinking right here - or do I need to regurgitate the events up the food chain so they will be available to the Winforms app ?

I have made the handlers in the base class like this:

```
    class MyClient<T> :DuplexClientBase<T> where T : class
    {
    protected virtual void InitializeClient()
    {
          base.InnerChannel.Faulted += InnerChannel_Faulted;
    }

     protected virtual void InnerChannel_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // ... do something()
    }

    }

class MyListener :  MyClient<MyListenerService>
{

public MyListener(){ // do stuff}
// .. other methods

}

WINDOWFORMAPP : FORM
{


  private MyListener mylistener = new MyListener();

  WINDOWFORMAPP()
{
// somehow subscribe to 
mylistener.InnerChannel_Faulted += 

}

  private override void InnerChannel_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // DoSomething to GUI - notifications GUI elements etc.. 
// then call.
  mylistener.InnerChannel_Faulted()
}

}
```

Comment: On the line `mylistener.InnerChannel_Faulted +=`, why not `mylistener.InnerChannel.Faulted += ...` ?

Comment: @Loathing How would I handle the event in the sub class - if I need to do some handling there for all the classes that might be derived from subclass, and then in the winform handle the same event only to provide functionality for the UI - or am I thinking about this the wrong way entirely ?

Comment: See edited answer, added `MySubclass` class. In the subclass, override the `protected` method, add whatever special handling is needed, and call `base.OnSomeAction(e);` to fire the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not standard to subscribe to the event from the same class or subclass. The usual approach is to structure the code as:

```
public class MyClass {
   public event EventHandler SomeAction;

   private void DoStuff() {
       bool fireAction = false;
       //....
       if (fireAction) {
          EventArgs e = ...; // can be more specific if needed
          OnSomeAction(e);
       }
   }

   protected virtual void OnSomeAction(EventArgs e) {
     if (SomeAction != null)
         SomeAction(this, e);
   }
}

public class MySubclass : MyClass {
   protected override void OnSomeAction(EventArgs e) {
      // code before event is triggered
      base.OnSomeAction(e); // fires event to listeners
      // code after event is triggered
   }

}
```

Then in your form:

```
public class MyForm : Form {

  MyClass mc = new MyClass();
  public MyForm() {
      mc.SomeAction += mc_SomeAction;
  }

  private void mc_SomeAction(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
     //...
  }
}
```

Comment: What I was trying to accomplish was to encapsulate a lot of handling in the client class - so I could instantiate it with the parameters and it will just run. The thing is though I would like my UI to get notifications of certain conditions - some I just want to know the channel is opened or closed. in case of faulted I might need to dispose my Client and recreate it.